# How to pass radio button having <%some code %> as its name to java action class?

Tags: java, jsp-tags

Here is my radio button in a form in my JSP:

```
<label>Present</label><input type = "radio" name = 'updateattendance +
<%=String.valueOf(search.getEmpId())%>' value = "present" />
<label>Absent</label><input type = "radio" name= 'updateattendance +
<%=String.valueOf(search.getEmpId())%>' value = "absent"/>`
```

The usual way to get the value of radio button in Java class is as follows:

```
String attStatus = request.getParameter("radiovalue");
```

where `radiovalue` is the name attribute of radio button in the JSP. But in my above code the name of radio button has some code.

```
'updateattendance + <%=String.valueOf(search.getEmpId())%>'
```

So how should I get it in my Java class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can iterate over parameter names and find parameter, which name starts with "updateattendance".

Here is code example:

```
Enumeration parameters = request.getParameterNames();
  while(parameters.hasMoreElements()) {
    String parameterName = parameters.nextElement().toString();
    if(parameterName.startsWith("updateattendance")){
       String parameterValue = request.getParameter(parameterName);
       // parameterValue is value of radio button parameter
    }
  }
```

Comment: Oleksandr.Bezhan:
Thanks for such prompt reply. Your code works perfectly well and it updates my database. the only problem is that I have 7 entries and it should update for those 7 entries. Instead the attendance table after updating has 49 entries. So it does 7*7=49. Is there any flow with the code? I have given the code in next comment.

Comment: public void updateDailyAttendance(ActionRequest areq, ActionResponse aRes)  throws Exception{
    
     
int totalEmployees = EmployeeLocalServiceUtil.getEmployeesCount();
         
for(int i=0;i<totalEmployees;i++)  {
           
           
Enumeration parameters = areq.getParameterNames();
  while(parameters.hasMoreElements()) {
String parameterName = parameters.nextElement().toString();          if(parameterName.startsWith("updateattendance")){
String parameterValue = areq.getParameter(parameterName);
}
}
}
}

Comment: You must get parameter value once and then use it in iteration.
Here is example: http://pastebin.com/2artmEJD

Comment: @ Oleksandr.Bezhan:  I am having a problem. When I try to use the above code it works well but the value that I enter for the first value is updated for all other employees instead of storing unique attendance value for each employee.. How should I change the code?